Where Does Rashi Mention the Streets of Venice?
After some discussion with some chavrusot, someone mentioned that there is a Rashi somewhere in Shas that discusses either the streets of Venice, or at least a city with "dry streets" surrounded by water. I cannot seem to locate a source for this using other methods. Has anyone heard of a mekor for this?

Perhaps this, in Rashi on Yeshayah 42:10:

ומלואו. הקבועים בים ולא באיים אלא בתוך המים שופכים עפר כל אחד ואחד כדי בית והולכים מבית לבית בספינה כגון עיר ווניציי"א:‏
"[Those who go down into the sea] and its fullness": who live permanently in the sea - not on islands, but within the water. Each person pours out enough dirt for [the foundation of] his house, and they travel from one house to another by boat, as in the city of Venice.


Thank you for this! I believe there was something just like this, but in Shas somewhere. Any way to confirm that?
